# With as many questions related to EC2, why close a very serious topic?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, amazon

I was recently linked the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284680/warning-about-amazon-ec2-urgent-if-you-use-this-service

In looking over many of the questions here, this site seems to have alot of questions About EC2.  While the post in question is not directly a question, it should still not simply be "closed" because its not a "real question".

So, my question is:
Why close an extremely important topic just because it is not a "clear and concise question"?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: Take the time to read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Yesterday we had Joseph Heller. Today, we've got Walter Cronkite. Awesome.

Comment: This really grinds my gears.

Answer (score 9):

Because this website (StackOverflow and it's sister sites) is set up specifically for "clear and concise questions".

**STOP TRYING TO MAKE THE SITE WHAT IT IS NOT SUPPOSED TO BE**

Someone else had the same issue and he got told rightly for it as well:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14763/why-are-my-questions-closed

Quoting my answer from the other topic:

> "Your idea of what you want
>   StackOverflow to be is obviously not
>   shared by the vast majority of the
>   community. This site was set up to be
>   the end-all-be-all source for
>   programming Q&A. If you have a
>   programming question that actually has
>   an answer, posting it will most likely
>   get you an answer.
>
> StackOverflow is not your personal
>   blog. It is not your philosophical
>   discussion and debate forum. If you
>   are constantly posting things that get
>   closed as "Not programming related" or
>   "not a real question" or any of the
>   other reasons, perhaps you need to
>   reevaluate your question asking before
>   you start pointing the fingers at the
>   hundreds/thousands of users who get by
>   perfectly fine under the current
>   community standards."

Comment: Perhaps it's because hundreds/thousands of users aren't the type to give input like we are.

Comment: If a large number of users aren't going to stand up and disagree, it is fair to assume that they agree. If the way things are being done now is not enough to cause them to revolt, then that is a silent endorsement.

Comment: You're right that apathy is a silent endorsement, that's why I refuse to be silent, because I refuse to be apathetic.

Comment: @Lance: Hell yeah you do. Or whatever.

Comment: **Fight The Power!** http://members.cox.net/fantasychamp/power.jpg

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of how important the topic may be, StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. It is a Q&A site, and you did not ask a question.

Take the time to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @Downvoter: here on meta, more than on SO, you need to say why you downvoted if you want to have an impact. Otherwise, you're a pebble in a lake, and the ripples will stop very soon.

Comment: @John Saunders: I would think almost completely the opposite. Since more often than not we are taking positions on something, a silent downvote will generally be seen as "No I don't agree with you". Whether that is enough to give you clue about why they disagreed or not, I don't know. And you weren't the only one to get the DV. I am already under the assumption that Lance (since the OP is not on this site) went and DV'ed all of us at once before posting his own answer.

Comment: @TheTXI: That was my guess as well, but I didn't want to assume it without giving Lance a chance to explain himself.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow isn't a review site, nor a general discussion board. If you want such information, you need to acquire it from another site.

Answer (score -6):

Because some people don't understand the importance of **important information**.

Next time, ask a question like "What critical problems are there with EC2?", and then post your own answer to it.  This is an SO acceptable way of doing things.

Comment: Still not programming related.

Comment: -1 for using Community Wiki to try and shield yourself from an answer you knew was going to get voted down.

Comment: You're second paragraph is possibly reasonable, although more appropriate for serverfault rather than stackoverflow. However I think you're first paragraph is just wrong - it's not about importance at all.

Comment: "Important information" is about the most ridiculously subjective thing you could have possibly said.  Do you honestly believe that the SO/SF/SU community should make an exception to posts because they are "important information"?  The thousand other sites catering to this type of "important information" are not enough for you?

Comment: Yah, I would have to agree with TheTXI on the community wiki post. Your not using the site features correctly.

Comment: "importance of important information" Best line.

Comment: @TheTXI: I'm sure you wouldn't understand since you're in the outspoken majority, in a true democracy the minority opinions always get clobbered.

Comment: @lance, what's your point?  *You* don't decide the rules, you simply get the ability to enforce them. SO is clearly a dictatorship ruled by Jeff from his secret base.